# Read / Write Memorystream in LocalFolder

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, storagefile

I need to read and write a MemoryStream
I coded this method but I have a bug on the loading method :

```
    public async void SaveToStorage(MemoryStream stream, String filename)
    {
        var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var storageFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        using (Stream x = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            x.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream.WriteTo(x);
        }
    }
```

and the method where there is a problem (I think):

```
public async Task<MemoryStream> LoadToStorage(string filename)
{
    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var storageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);

    using (var fileStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return memoryStream;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks you for some help

Comment: And what is the actual nature of the problem? You've told us where you think the problem may lie, but not *what it is*.

Comment: When I read the file like this : " var myMyMemoryStream = await mp.LoadFromStorage(myFile);   if (_dataContext.ImageNewStream.Length == 0) ..." I have an exception : 'myMyMemoryStream.Length' a levé une exception de type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'

Comment: OK, so the problem is just the one I guessed at in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to have the `MemoryStream` you create in your `LoadToStorage` method in a `using` statement, because presumably, the caller isn't expecting you to hand back an object that's been `Dispose`d:

```
public async Task<MemoryStream> LoadToStorage(string filename)
{
    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var storageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);

    using (var fileStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return memoryStream;
    }
}
```